# Crystal Reports 8.5 report runs stored procedure twice

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-8.5

I created a report that uses a SQL Server stored procedure as a data source. Through the use of SQL Server Profiler I found out that when loading the report in our application the report runs the stored procedure 2 times instead of just 1 time. The first time it runs with the parameters that where used to create the report and the second time ut runs with the parameters that the application specified. The first run is unnecasary and causes the report to load much slower. Especially with long running queries. I already turned off the option "Verify on Every print" but that didn't help. When Googling I found many answer but they all target higher versions of Crystal Reports. An option like "verify stored procedure on first refresh" is not available in Crystal Reports 8.5. So how to disable that first request?

Comment: As a workaround, redesign your report to use such combination of sp parameters, which makes sp run very fast :) I don't know about real solution.

Comment: Could you update the question to include the code from your application that executes the report?  It may also help to describe how your database is setup within the report.